# Bit level manipulation in Java / reinterpreted_cast<> in Java?

Tags: java, casting, bit-manipulation

Is there anyway to treat as a float an int's value (and back)? Like this:

```
int myInt = 1729;
float myFloat = intToFloatPreservingBitPattern(myInt);
int otherInt = floatToIntPreservingBitPattern(myFloat);
```

(in C++ I could use `float myFloat = reinterpreted_cast<float>(myInt)`, I'm looking for something similar in Java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Float.intBitsToFloat` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat-int-).

The reverse is the [`Float.floatToIntBits` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits-float-).

Comment: Thanks, is there anything for the reverse?. Thanks! =D

Comment: Yes; I've added to my answer.